# Redirect a user roll to a page after login in mutlisite network

Tags: multisite, user-roles

Trying to redirect a custom user role to a page after login on a specific blog in a multisite network, from what I checked, the isset( $user->roles ) does not pass

```
/**
* Redirect users to page after log in 
*/
function ak_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
//is there a user to check?
global $user;

if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {

    if ( in_array( 'custom_members', $user->roles ) ) {
        // redirect them to the default place
        return home_url() . '/custom-page/';

    } else {

        return home_url();

    }

} else {

    return $redirect_to;

}
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'ak_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Have you tried a `print_r($user)` to make sure a user is present at that hook? Could try `get_current_user()` if it isn't present then.

Comment: Also double-check whether `$user->roles` actually returns the roles. I seem to remember some confusion around this, and it may be returning the capabilities rather than the roles.